# How to access DI from model in a generic way?

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

I have the following class (only the relevant part):

```
import { AppInjector } from '@app/shared/utility/app-injector';
import { HttpService } from '@app/shared/services/http.service';

export class Lazy<T> {

    private readonly _http: HttpService = AppInjector.get(HttpService);

    private _init() {
        // Usage of this._http
    }
}
```

So basically, this is a simple type but that needs to use the Angular `HttpService`.
To do so, I created a file with the following code:

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

export let AppInjector: Injector;

export function setAppInjector(injector: Injector) {
    if (AppInjector) {
        console.error('Programming error: AppInjector was already set');
    }
    else {
        AppInjector = injector;
    }
}
```

And I'm setting it in the constructor of my `AppModule`:

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        setAppInjector(injector);
    }
}
```

Finally, I use it for example in a service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FooService {

    private readonly ROUTE: string = "/api/foo";

    private _campaigns: Lazy<ICampaign[]> = new Lazy<ICampaign[]>(`${this.ROUTE}/campaigns`);

    public get campaigns(): Lazy<ICampaign[]> {
        return this._campaigns;
    }
}
```

And in a component, I can do something like:

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _fooService: FooService) {}

    public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
        await this._fooService.campaigns.load();
    }
}
```

This works pretty well but I'm wondering how I could make this more generic.
Indeed, say I wanted to create a separate npm package with just this class, I can't tell users to create the `setAppInjector` function and to register it in the `AppModule` (and I could not even use it from my npm package anyway...).

So I'm searching for an Angular way to make this generic, something like passing something in the `providers` property of the decorator of the `AppModule`.

Any idea?

Comment: That class can not be a service?

Comment: I edited my question by explaining how I use this class. I think it should answer your question, if not, maybe you're onto something ;-)

Comment: To be honest I will still make it as service. Could you say way you do not want to make it as service?

Comment: Well, maybe there is something I don't know but would you be able to use a service like I'm using the class right now ? Note that you could have multiple variable of type `Lazy<T>` that differs only by the parameters sent to its constructor. I don't really see how you would use a service in here.

Comment: Ok I see now your point that you expect to have multiple instances of Lazy within single component, which will use different url. But it still not be a problem to use service with methods which will as parameter get an url and get and than set proper variables.